# use Console Application with GUI Application?

Tags: delphi, console-application

How could I create a Console Application that could work with or without a GUI?

For example, say if I had a console application, If i tried launching this console app from Windows Explorer it will not work it will just close, but I could call it from my GUI Application or the Windows Command Console (cmd.exe) and pass some switches (parameters?) to it.

That way some useful functions can be used without even starting the GUI Application, they can be called from the command line.

**EDIT**

I am not sure how to create the Console Application, especially that would accept flags (switches, parameters?).

I have seen some Applications that do something similar. For example they might have a Console Application that will convert a bmp to a png, and the GUI calls this Console Application and passes the arguments etc to it.

Hope that makes sense.

So how could I employ something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: It is very hard to understand whay to mean. The "it will not work" part is easy to answer. In fact, it *does* work, and I talk about it in my answer below.

Comment: yeah I dont think I explained my question very clear, I am thinking of how I can reword it better...

Comment: You might be interested in this article: [oldnewthing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/01/01/9259142.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> For example, say if I had a console application, If i tried launching this console app from Windows Explorer it will not work it will just close, but I could call it from my GUI Application or the Windows Command Console (cmd.exe) and pass some switches (parameters?) to it.

It *will* work. However, the console window will disappear as soon as your program has exited. If you want to give the user a chance to read the output of your console application before the window is closed, simply end your program with a single

```
Readln;
```

or

```
Writeln('Press Enter to exit.');
Readln;
```

If you want to use a console window for output (or input) in a GUI application, you can give the `AllocConsole` and `FreeConsole` functions a try.

Command-line arguments (such as `myapp.exe /OPEN "C:\some dir\file.txt" /THENEXIT`) can be used in all types of Windows applications, both GUI apps and console apps. Just use the `ParamCount` and `ParamStr` functions.

**How to Create a Console Application that Accepts Command-Line Arguments**

In the Delphi IDE, choose File/New/Console Application. Then write

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows, SysUtils;

var
  freq: integer;

begin

  if ParamCount = 0 then
    Writeln('No arguments passed.')

  else if ParamCount >= 1 then

    if SameText(ParamStr(1), '/msg') then
    begin

        if ParamCount = 1 then
          Writeln('No message to display!')
        else
          MessageBox(0, PChar(ParamStr(2)), 'My Console Application',
            MB_ICONINFORMATION);

    end

    else if SameText(ParamStr(1), '/beep') then
    begin

      freq := 400;

      if ParamCount >= 2 then
        if not TryStrToInt(ParamStr(2), freq) then
          Writeln('Invalid frequency: ', ParamStr(2));

      Windows.Beep(freq, 2000);

    end;


end.
```

Compile the program. Then open a command processor (CMD.EXE) and go to the directory where `Project1.exe` is.

Then try

```
C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects>project1
No arguments passed.

C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects>project1 /msg
No message to display!

C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects>project1 /msg "This is a test."

C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects>project1 /beep

C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects>project1 /beep 600

C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Documents\RAD Studio\Projects>
```

**How to pass three arguments**

```
if ParamCount >= 1 then
begin

  if SameText(ParamStr(1), '/CONVERT') then
  begin

    // The user wants to convert

    if ParamCount <= 2 then
    begin
      Writeln('Too few arguments!');
      Exit;
    end;

    FileName1 := ParamStr(2);
    FileName2 := ParamStr(3);

    DoConvert(FileName1, FileName2);

  end;

end;
```

Comment: Andreas, please could you help me pass two filenames as an argument. ie from cmd.exe something like: /convert "file1.bmp" "file2.jpg" thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> *That way some useful functions can be used without even starting the GUI Application, they can be called from the command line.*

If you want the application to be a GUI application, but you want to override the GUI by passing command line parameters, then try someting like this:

```
program Project1;

uses
  Forms,
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Unit1 in 'Unit1.pas' {Form1};

{$R *.res}

begin
  if ParamCount > 0 then
    Windows.MessageBox(GetDesktopWindow, PChar(ParamStr(1)), PChar('Test'), 0)
  else
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
    Application.Run;
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to achieve this in delphi but in C# I just checked in the Main method if any command line arguments had been passed in, if there were then run the application with a console if there were none run the GUI.